# LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN using LINQ Entity-Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Trying joining using Linq. 
What should i use ?  Left join or right join?

```
     APPLICANT TABLE                         PROFILE TABLE
APPLICANT_ID|profile_id|Applicant_Name| |profile_id|Applicant_Name  
      1     |    NULL  |  RAY HEAVENS | |    1     | MARK LAPID
      2     |    NULL  |  BEN TULFO   | |    2     | SUPER MAN
      3     |     1    |      NULL    | |    3     | BRANDON KNIGHT
      4     |     2    |      NULL    | |
      5     |     3    |      NULL    | |

DESIRED OUTPUT: 

APPLICANT_ID | Applicant_Name
      1      |   RAY HEAVENS
      2      |   BEN TULFO
      3      |   MARK LAPID
      4      |   SUPERMAN
      5      |   BRANDON KNIGHT
```

This is my code in my controller:

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles 
                     join app in context.APPLICANTs
                     on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into output
                     from j in output.DefaultIfEmpty(new APPLICANT())
                     select j ).Take(1000).AsEnumerable();

                   applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();


            if (applicantdata.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
        return applicantdata;

    }
```

I hope someone can recommend me what to use or what to do.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would believe `.DefaultIfEmpty()` translates into a `LEFT JOIN`, have you profiled it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated for the error: *You will need to create a new class with the required properties and return it.*

```
    var applicantList = (from app in context.APPLICANTs
                         join a in context.Profiles
                         on app.Profile_id equals a.PROFILE_ID into output
                         from j in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { APPLICANT_ID = app.APPLICANT_ID, Applicant_Name = (j == null ? app.Applicant_Name : j.Applicant_Name) }).Take(1000).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: sir . . now im experiencing Exception 

`Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Applicant.Models.APPLICANT>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
` 

at

`applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
`

Comment: Sir @cheedep Thank you but now theres a new exception at `applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList(); `the new exception is `NotSupported Exception was unhandled by user code The entity or complex type 'Model.APPLICANT' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query`